# Implement a listener for a Class instead of an instance

Tags: android, events, listener, android-broadcast

I have **a lot** of instances of class `MyClass` and they **ALL** have to react to some generated event from another class `MyEventClass`. How should I do this?

My first thought was to define a listener in `MyEventClass` and implement it in `MyClass`, but this would require for every instance of `MyClass` to set the listener, and in addition to define the listener as an array in `MyEventClass`.
A lot of code/work.

Another option I thought is to use broadcast in `MyEventClass` and receivers in `MyClass`, but I am not sure, maybe is overkilling, and the receivers are to be registered as well (and unregistered on `onStop()`)

A third option would  be to define the listener implementation for the class `MyClass`, not for each instance, this would fit perfectly, but I don't know if it is possible at all and how do I go about coding it.

Yet a fourth option I just came up with, is to implement the listener on the parent class of `MyClass` and only setting this listener in `MyEventClass`, then on the event occurrence loop through all `MyClass` instances and manually call their listeners. This saves me registering each instance with `MyEventClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StinePike is right on this one, this is a very standard problem to encounter when coding. The Observer (or Listener in Java talk) pattern is the standard-practice solution to this. You should use your first proposition, which you worded kind of unclear, so I'll lay it out for you in case I'm not being too clear.

Let `MyEventClass` offer a Listener interface, like `MyEventClassListener`, and add/remove methods. Then `MyClass` can attach/detach themselves as listeners. Here's a code example in case you need it:

**MyEventClass.java**

```
public class MyEventClass {

    private Set<MyEventClassListener> listeners = new HashSet<MyEventClassListener>();

    // Your code here...

    public void addListener(MyEventClassListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(MyEventClassListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void notifyListeners() {
        for (MyEventClassListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.somethingHappened();
        }
    }

}
```

**MyEventClassListener.java**

```
public interface MyEventClassListener {

    public void somethingHappened();

}
```

**MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass implements MyEventClassListener {

    MyEventClass myEventClass;

    // Your code here..

    public void someFunction() {
        // Add as listener
        myEventClass.addListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void somethingHappened() {
        // Act on callback
    }

}
```

Comment: So, no break for the lazy programmer!

Comment: You can't avoid what you can't avoid :)

Answer (score 3):

I think `Observer design pattern` will be your best choice..

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object,
>   called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called
>   observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes,
>   usually by calling one of their methods. It is mainly used to implement distributed event handling systems

with thousands of other links you can check these [link1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), [link2](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)

Comment: How is Observer different from BroadcastReceiver? =>  Observer == Receiver, ObserverCollection == EventClass, notify() == sendBroadcast(), plus observers have to be registered the same as Receivers.

Comment: no the concept is different .. . check this https://sites.google.com/site/cliangusf/courses/mobile-programming/exploring-broadcast-receivers

Comment: Frankly I don't see the difference, though answer 0 says so. it also says *"Observer pattern is different, a subject register a list of observers, and subject informs all the observers when change happend."* which is exactly what can be done with BroadcastReceivers too, maybe BroadcastReceiver can do more than Observer-Pattern. In any case, it is one of the possible options I describe and I take you recommend that way over the others, a valid advise, thank you.